# Mapping of primitive data type from Java to objective-C using j2objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, primitive-types, j2objc

I am translating a big project from Java to objective-C. When there are primitive data types, they will be translated to JNI Types instead of objective-C data types, such as boolean -> jboolean.

However, it is written in the documentation that the mapping should be directly from boolean to BOOL.

What I expect is it could translate from boolean to BOOL directly. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [jboolean is typedef'd as a BOOL](https://github.com/google/j2objc/blob/master/jre_emul/Classes/J2ObjC_types.h#L36) when referenced from an Objective-C source. The translator used to output BOOL directly, but switched to jboolean (as well as jchar, jint, etc.) so JNI sources can be built without modification.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your work! It is a nice tool!